# Splash screen fade-out in titanium

Tags: titanium

I want to fade out the splash screen.

I think it's possible in native code android or iOS.

However for titanium which way is the appropriate ??

for now my source code is this

```
var topWin = Ti.UI.createWindow();// main application window.

var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : '/img/Default.png',
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    width : '100%',
    height : '100%'
});

var splash = Ti.UI.createWindow(); //splash window
splash.add(img);

splash.open();

var fadeOut = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    opacity : 0.2,
    duration : 300
});
var fadeIn = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    opacity : 1,
    duration : 1800
});

setTimeout(function(e) {
    splash.close(fadeOut);
    topWin.open(fadeIn);
}, 3000);
```

It works as I mean however I think this way might be a bit strange.

Since 
I have to decide the each image according to different resolution devices(iphone/ipad/android ,,) by manual while splash screen is chosen automatically.

Is there a good way other than this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:
http://www.tidev.io/2015/01/06/how-to-re-use-the-launch-image-in-the-app/

I haven't done this in a while, and I'm not sure if the changes to 5.2 SDK for iOS for Storyboard launch files breaks this method but here's where I'd start.